# Excel VBA - Multiline Highest value

Tags: vba

I have a multi-line cell with the below data, I need a function which finds highest age and give result. You can find age in the brackets. If multiple people have same age with highest age it should give both as output in a cell

Example:1

```
Ravi (11)\,Chandra (22)\,Krishna (22)\,Hemanth (11)
```

for the above date it should give output as below in a cell:

```
Chandra (22)\,Krishna (22)
```

Example:2

```
Ravi (11)\,Chandra (23)\,Krishna (22)\,Hemanth (11)
```

Output as below in a cell:

```
Chandra (23)
```

Comment: The output should give a line not single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this function:

```
Function AgeResult(cellVal As String) As String
    Dim elem As Variant
    Dim maxAgeNames As String
    Dim iniPos As Long, endPos As Long
    Dim maxAge As Long, age As Long

    For Each elem In Split(cellVal, ",")
        iniPos = InStr(elem, "(")
        endPos = InStr(elem, ")")
        age = Mid(elem, iniPos + 1, endPos - iniPos - 1)
        If age >= maxAge Then
            If age > maxAge Then
                maxAge = age
                maxAgeNames = elem
            Else
                maxAgeNames = maxAgeNames & "," & elem
            End If
        End If
    Next elem
    AgeResult = maxAgeNames
End Function
```

a possible use of which is what follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A10") '<~~ range of cells to process the content of
        cell.Offset(, 1) = AgeResult(cell.Value) '<~~ this puts the resulting string in the adjacent cell to the right
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: that's precisely it. have you tested it?

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!!! Tested thoroughly ....small request can u implement within the function without using Sub routine.

Comment: Not clear what you mean: please give more details. In any case since I answered your _original_ question (which requested a function to process a multiline cell content) please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.